# Bootstrap vue @ok is not been triggered

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a vue bootstrap modal and I am trying to capture the ok event, but seems that is not been triggered, what am I missing?

```
<b-modal class="modal-md"
          ok-title="Invite"
          ref="myModal"
          title="Hellow world"
          @hidden="onHidden"
          @ok="myMethod"
         :ok-disabled="!validForm">


methods:{ 
    myMethod() {
        console.log('ok')
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? This looks fine

Comment: Are you using the latest version of BootstrapVue?

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code in my answer
here is my code please use in your code and let me know

```
<b-modal class="modal-md"
          ok-title="Invite"
          ref="myModal"
          title="Hellow world"
          @hidden="onHidden"
          @ok="myMethod"
         :ok-disabled="false">
         My Modal
  </b-modal>
```

For open this

```
this.$refs['myModal'].show()
```

Methods

```
methods: {
 onHidden(){
      console.log("hide")
    },
    myMethod(){
      console.log("myMethod")
    }
}
```